# Jenkins giving Content Encoding Error

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using [subversion merge plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Merge+Plugin) version 1.2 with Jenkins ver. 1.516  , and after running the job, when i try to access

http://:8080/job/perlapp_install/integration-status

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
  Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

instead of what i should be getting is:

[image: integration-status]

/var/log/jenkins.log when i click on the link Integration status:

```
Jun 05, 2013 10:00:35 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
WARNING: Untrapped Error in Servlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:231:26: <d:invokeBody> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21: <d:invokeBody> java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:280)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.layout(Unknown Source)
at lib.LayoutTagLib$layout.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index.run(index.groovy:11)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:69)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:62)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:666)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$12.dispatch(MetaClass.java:384)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:66)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:98)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:86)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:84)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:98)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:231:26: <d:invokeBody> org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21: <d:invokeBody> java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:276)
... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21: <d:invokeBody> java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:280)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.main_panel(Unknown Source)
at lib.LayoutTagLib$main_panel.call(Unknown Source)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index$_run_closure1.doCall(index.groovy:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index$_run_closure1.doCall(index.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder$1.run(JellyBuilder.java:264)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
... 80 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.516.jar!/lib/layout/main-panel.jelly:36:21: <d:invokeBody> java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:276)
... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.Functions.getRelativeLinkTo(Functions.java:940)
at hudson.Functions$getRelativeLinkTo.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index$_run_closure1_closure2_closure4.doCall(index.groovy:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index$_run_closure1_closure2_closure4.doCall(index.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:296)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.methodMissing(JellyBuilder.java:173)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor180.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:811)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1103)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1056)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:704)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovyClosureScript.invokeMethod(GroovyClosureScript.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:407)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:346)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:704)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:407)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:346)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(index.groovy:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at jenkins.plugins.svnmerge.IntegrationStatusAction.index$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(index.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder$1.run(JellyBuilder.java:264)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
... 115 more
```

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/754411 perhaps, will fix the problem , but i am leaning towards jenkins fixing it rather than modifying Firefox config.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, not sure if it same case as yours, but in my case I had a folder plugin and had both jobs inside these folders, then race condition arise.

Then I tried leaving both jobs at the root level in the dashboard and then it worked like a charm.

Hope this helps.
Regards